# how to render scene in blender with layer and volumetric atmosphere

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, render-layers, viewlayers

I have a problem with rendering a scene correctly using layers. When I render it as a whole everything is fine.
When I use layers I have a problem with volumetric atmosphere which obscures everything behind. What can be done to get the same look when using layers as when rendering without them?
[image]

[image]